# Is it possible to create log based alert for Constraints in GCP using python at organization level?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to create log based (stackdriver) alerts for GCP constraints at org level??? Creating alerts at project level is possible, but want to know if we can create alerts at Organization level, if so, how to do that..

Comment: If any posted answer has helped you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the log-based alerts can only be created at project level.

I think that this could be a workaround for your case:

**1. Create an [aggregated sink](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_sinks) to route audit log entries for your Google Cloud organization.**

> To create a sink, use the `logging sinks create` command.
>
> Supply the sink name, sink destination, filter, and the ID of the
> folder or organization from which you're routing logs:
>
> ```
> gcloud logging sinks create SINK_NAME
> SINK_DESTINATION  --include-children \
> --folder=FOLDER_ID filter
> ```
>
> For example, if you're creating an aggregated sink at the folder level
> and whose destination is a BigQuery dataset, your command might look
> like the following:
>
> ```
> gcloud logging sinks create SINK_NAME \
> bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/datasets/DATASET_ID --include-children \
> --folder=FOLDER_ID --log-filter="logName:activity"
> ```
>
> Notes:
>
> To create a sink at the organization level, replace
> `--folder=FOLDER_ID` with `--organization=ORGANIZATION_ID`.
>
> - For the sink to include all resources within the organization, the    --include-children flag must be set, even when the --organization flag is passed to create. When set to false (the default), a sink    will
>   only route logs from the host resource.
> - Retrieve the service account name used to create the sink from the    command output.
> - Give that service account permission to write to your sink    destination.
> - If you don't have permission to make that change to the sink    destination, then send the service account name to someone who can
>   make that change for you.
>
> For more information about granting service accounts permissions for
> resources, see the set destination permissions section.

**2. You can set the destination of the [sink to Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs#pubsub-overview) so that you can trigger an email alert whenever the sink routes the audit log.**

> Logs routed to Pub/Sub are generally available within seconds, with
> 99% of logs available in less than 60 seconds.
>
> To view your routed logs as they are streamed through Pub/Sub, do the
> following:
>
> - Go to the Pub/Sub page in the Cloud Console.
> - Find or create a subscription to the topic used in the log sink, and    pull a log entry from it. You might have to wait for a new log
>   entry    to be published.

Comment: What I am trying to do create an alert notification whenever a GCP constraint is created, deleted, or updated..                  

So, if I create a sink with command below   -> gcloud logging sinks create SINK_NAME \
bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/datasets/DATASET_ID --include-children \
--Organization=ORG_ID --log-filter="protoPayload.methodName=google.cloud.orgpolicy.v2.OrgPolicy.CreatePolicy    ,



We are checking constraints at org level, but what if I want to include project level and folder level constraints tooo..

Comment: You can also create aggregated sinks to specify that your sink combine and route log entries from the Google Cloud resources contained by an organization or folder. For instructions, see [Configure aggregated sinks](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/aggregated_sinks).
Without the aggregated sink feature, sinks are limited to routing log entries from the exact resource in which the sink was created: a Google Cloud project, organization, folder, or billing account.